# Bad T-SQL procedure performance on Azure Cloud platform

Tags: performance, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

We are observing Strange behavior on Azure Cloud platform

Problem Statement :
We have developed T-SQL Stored procedures to transform data from CSV file to target data model.
We are running these procedures on approximately 7 Lac records (700000)

Issue is with the execution time of these procedures on Different enviornment

Cloud Platform (Azure SQL) : 2 hrs - 2hrs-30 min

Laptop AMD A8 PRO 1.9 GHZ (SQL Server 2014) RAM 8GB : 22 mins

Desktop Intel i3 6100 T 3.20 GHZ (SQL Server 2014) RAM 8GB : 5 mins 52 secs

Ideally we expect procedures to run faster on production servers but here the case is reverse.

From Laptop Vs Desktop execution times we can observe the procedures run faster with Higher CPU Speed and processing power.

We are asked to reduce the execution times of these procedures from 2 hrs 30 mins to under 40 mins on Cloud.

We do have indexes in place in required places , but I'm not able to understand this difference in execution time on Azure Vs Desktop/Laptop

Any Suggestions what can be done here

Comment: Are you using SQL in a VM, or Azure SQL Databases? And if you're using the latter, which tier are you using?

Comment: We are using Azure SQL Database , I'm not sure about the tier (Would need to connect with Dev-Ops team for this info)
Is there a easy way to find out may be using a query ?

Comment: You can find out the SQL Tier with PowerShell [Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/get-azuresqldatabaseserviceobjective?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)

Comment: its Basic Subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stated you are using an Azure SQL Database in the Basic tier. This means you have **5 DTU's** available for the database. *This is the absolute lowest you can go for Azure SQL Databases.*

For information on DTU's, have a look at [DTU based purchasing model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers#dtu-based-purchasing-model).

Please be advised that you can scale the amount of DTU's available for your database by choosing a different tier. This goes up as high as **4000 DTU's** in the P15 tier. That's an increase of 800%.

Another solution would be to investigate the [vCore-based purchasing model (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers#vcore-based-purchasing-model--preview).

[image: DTU-based model vs. vCore-based model]

Comment: Thanks it seems lower DTU's are the problem here , its upto the architects now to take the upgrade decision

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot performance issues, you must complete a series of steps to isolate and determine the cause of the problem.

You can use performance insight tool. It records all the queries and shows you the performance of the db. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-query-performance/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , but we do not have direct access to database. (Can't even a fire a select * from tablename directly :( )
We do everything via dev-ops pipeline